# Nail clippers and conservation of momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, everyday-life

As I clip my fingernails using nail clippers, pieces of nails sometimes fly off violently, reaching the other end of the room. What's happening in terms of conservation of momentum, how are the pieces able to acquire so much of it? After all, my pressure on the clippers is in a different direction altogether and there's very little movement of the clippers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not about momentum. The total momentum is conserved: the fingernail flies in one direction, and you (plus the nail clipper) suffer a recoil to the opposite direction. The thing is that your piece of fingernail has a very small mass compared to your body mass, and the firing speed is actually not so high, so the recoil is negligible.

About why the fingernail goes flying... well the situation is something like this:

[image: nail clipping]

A nail clipper usually is a combination of levers, and the blades work like a double wedge. The force you apply accumulate in the flexible levers, until the force is enough to clip the nail, then the nail breaks, and the blades collapse violently one towards the other. The release piece of nail is pushed by the inclined plane of the wedge.

The firing speed of the nail piece is proportional to the collapsing speed of the blades, and depends on the slope of the profile of the blade.